# How do I make a cloth like this in the air?

Tags: sculpting, cloth-simulation

How to make a cloth still in air without anything to interact with[image]

Comment: Hi Simran. I know you are new here. But we cannot look in your brain and know what you are thinking so please tell us as detailed as possible what you want to do. You can edit your question by clicking on "edit". Else you gonna risk that your question will be closed soon. This is a pretty frustrating experience. Do you want to make an animation? Without interacting anything -> how should it "fly" then? So i think you mean not interacting with obstacles? If you wanna make an animation you can work with force fields. But because i don't know what you want...i won't write an answer....

Comment: No I don’t want an animation, I just want to make a stationary 3d model that looks like a cloth thats in the air like this. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a plane, subdivide it, give it a *Cloth* simulation, select the left edge and assign it to a group that will be the cloth *Pin Group*, enable the *Self Collisions* option, create 2 *Force Fields*: one *Wind* and One *Turbulence*, play the animation, stop it at the frame you want and apply the *Cloth* modifier:

[image]

The other solution would be to use the same plane but sculpt it with the *Cloth* brush, which would give something like that:

[image]